# gitlab-shell -> git push -u origin master -> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm using gitlab-shell to manage git connections and here is my problem :

```
$ git push -v -u origin master
Pushing to git@git.my-srv.fr:monProjet.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

```
# tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Mar 15 15:53:12 my-srv sshd[3133]: Accepted publickey for git from my-ip port 50790 ssh2
Mar 15 15:53:12 my-srv sshd[3133]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Mar 15 15:53:12 my-srv sshd[3285]: Received disconnect from my-ip: 11: disconnected by user
Mar 15 15:53:12 my-srv sshd[3133]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user git
```

So everybody say it's the other fault?! How can I have more informations about the git/ssh network exchange?

Comment: `ssh -vT git@git.my-srv.fr`?

Comment: here are the result (it's too long tu copy it in comment) http://pastebin.com/TUsj8aSA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've tried this :
**$ ssh -vT git@git.my-srv.fr**

I've see in the log an http redirect 301. (my proxy server redirect http to https)

I've correct it in gitlab-shell config, file : **/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml**

```
# Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls
gitlab_url: "https://git.my-srv.fr/"
```

the new error message was a ssl certificate verification fail (my certificate is auto-signed with no 3rd part autority)

so i've modified  **/home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb**
to add this :

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if (http.use_ssl?)
```

between these lines :

```
http.use_ssl = (url.port == 443)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if (http.use_ssl?)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
```

Like describe on this gitlab-shell closed pull request (and issue) :
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/pull/9

And here is the original commit content :
https://github.com/jcockhren/gitlab-shell/commit/846ee24697f386cd9fcbc4ab1a7fb8ae1ccb46ee

Answer (score 5):

Since the version 5.4, you can to edit on **gitlab-shell/config.yml**

> self_signed_cert: true

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the config.yml for gitlab-shell to point to the right URL fixed it for me (although I'm pushing using git@..)

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/65

> The config.yml of gitlab-shell should correctly point the URL. In my case it was http://git.domain.com:8080/.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same behavior on my gitlab installation. In my case it was a problem with the ssl certificates. It was hard to catch because:

```
https://gitlab.example.com  ==> padlock shows up, everything seems OK
openssl s_client -connect   ==> Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify...
```

Since gitlab uses openssl to verify the ssl connection, it exits fatal when openssl complains. The problem was fixed by creating a "correct" cert for my server gitlab.example.com by pasting:

```
ROOT-issuers-cert
Intermediate-cert
cert-for-example.com
```

into one text file.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this thread like me searching on the error ..

It's clear the error arrives when git can't access the gitlab webserver. For me it was a http user authentication I had put on nginx. After removing it, the error was gone.